# impossible to retrieve images

Tags: php, curl

and sorry for my bad English I'm doing a script to recover from my old blog on my new site, but I can not get this kind of link and I have no access to the server setting "unfortunately lowcost hosting .
I can recover the images of a direct link without worry but I can not recover the images with this kind of link

```
**the file and recover well with the correct size but the image is corrupt**

**http://hack.idleman.fr/action.php?action=get_resource_image&id=36** 
<pre>
downloadFile('http://hack.idleman.fr/action.php?action=get_resource_image&id=36','img/cms/toto.png');
</pre>
<pre>
function downloadFile($url, $path)
{
    $newfname = $path;
    $file = fopen($url, 'rb');
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen($newfname, 'wb');
        if ($newf) {
            while (!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8), 1024 * 8);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }
    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
</pre>

**or even with this code**

<pre>
downloadImage('http://hack.idleman.fr/action.php?action=get_resource_image&id=36','img/cms/toto.png');
function downloadImage($url,$filename){
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        @unlink($filename);
    }
    $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
    if($fp){
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = parse_url($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $result['scheme'].'://'.$result['host']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
        $raw=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if($raw){
            fwrite($fp, $raw);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        if(!$raw){
            @unlink($filename);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Use this windows software. I have used it many time to get all the html files images, js etc.: https://www.httrack.com/

Comment: the problem and that I made a script that inject Sql and images directly on my new site thanks anyway for the idea